# Java Wrapper & Primitive Memory Allocation

Tags: java, memory-management

I was asked following question in a interview

> ### Consider this following Code
>
> > `int i =0` 
> >     `Integer e1 = 0` 
> >     In which memory are they going to be created?

As per my understanding

> > For `int i =0`
> >
> > > Primitive data type goes into stack memory and
> >
> > For`Integer e1 = 0`
> >
> > > Integer been a Wrapper Class goes into heap memory

Please help with the proper understanding?

Comment: Yes your understanding is right. But the JLS allows for Integers in the range -128 to 127 to be stored as static instances within Integer class.

Comment: For a local reference variable like `e1` here, the reference itself will be on the stack, but the object that it refers to will be on the heap.

Answer (score 16):

It is a bit more complicated than that.

First, you need to know whether the `i` and `ei` variables are local variables or fields (static or instance) of an object<sup>1</sup>.

If they are local variables:

- `i` is on the stack.
- `ei` is on the stack (a reference) and it refers to an object in the heap.

If they are fields of an instance or class:

- `i` is on the heap (as part of the instance or the class).
- `ei` is on the heap (as part of the instance or the class) and it refers to an object in the heap.

Finally, it is worth noting that `Integer e1 = 0` may not allocate a new `Integer` object at all.  The reference stored in `e1` may be a reference to an object that already existed.

---

<sup>1 - There's another case too.  If `i` or `ei` are local variables that are referred to by an inner class declaration, then a second copy will be made when the inner class is instantiated.  For that copy, the space usage will be as if `i` / `ei` were fields of the inner class.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This one is a very interesting question.

With the primitive the allocation will be in the stack and will cost its needed 4 bytes give or take some rounding.

But things really begin to grow when talking about the wrapper.
If we compare it to C++, the fact that the 4 bytes will be allocated in the heap, makes the e1 a pointer.

Assuming we are using a 64bit machine, e1 will take 8bytes in the stack (+rounding).

And the heap data chunk has at least a small 4-8bytes header.

Looking inside the implementation of these types I don't see more memory used for each instance as all helper members and constants are static, so all instances will use the same data chunk in the 'data-segment' used for this type.

So, adding all this shows that the wrapper's allocation will always be bigger than the primitive.
For example - with extremely rough calculation you get something like:

Primitive: int ->  4 bytes,  Wrapper: Integer -> 8(stack) + 4 + 4 = 16 bytes

As for performance, it seems that primitives will be manipulated way faster than wrappers, but this is for another discussion.

Hope this info had helped.